# How do I connect to a jabber.org account with Chatsecure?

Tags: encryption, chat, xmpp

When I set up my `jabber.org` account in Chatsecure it doesn't connect. Another account on `jabber.ccc.de` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the automatically added server "hermes.jabber.org". Just leave the field empty.

See https://dev.guardianproject.info/issues/2803